# Form visible at runtime, but not at design time

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

My project has no errors, I'm able to run it via F5, but I can't look at my "main" 
form, as the [Design] tab tells me, "To prevent possible data loss before loading 
the designer, the following errors must be resolved: The class name "?" is not a 
valid identifier for this language."

But the Error List that contains that Description says it's at Line 0 and Column 0.

Build | Clean Solution did not help.

The Call Stack from the [Design] page is:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationFromCodeClass(CodeClass vsClass)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnNamespacePopulateTypes(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace.get_Types()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

### UPDATE

A shutdown of VS2010 and restart solved it.

Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WHYDTELPAGE)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true

I found a few suggestions, including this one (but I didn't need to try it, as making VS go to its room for a minute or two before coming back out worked):

*"delete the [solutionname].suo file which contains designer layout info from your previous session, then start the project and rebuild.."*

Comment: Do you have any custom controls that are being referenced?

Comment: Try looking for any custom controls or user controls where you have a constructor with parameters.  The designer doesn't like those controls and that *could be* the cause of the error.

Comment: @Justin and Lars: The only custom control in this solution is a DevArt dotConnect for Oracle OracleConnection component, but it's not on this form. I do have some overloaded constructors that take params; no user controls in this app. This is definitely bad form on somebody's part, but I don't know if it's me or Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember I saw this before. According to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/497218/the-class-name-is-not-a-valid-identifier-for-this-language-can-reproduce-w-vs-2008) it might be a compilation issue (too many brackets) which happens in VS2008 and won't surprise me if it happens in VS2010 too.

Answer (score 1):

Just Close the project and re-open.

Problem  resolved My project

Answer (score 1):

Restarting visual studio 2010 did the trick for me, it surely seems like a bug though.